# asp.net session state

Tags: asp.net, session

During Session Start, one has access to the Request object.  How about Session End, does it still have access to the Request object ?  For example I want to count how many browsers are currently connected to my application.

Edit 1 : If Session End doesn't have access to Request Object, what info does it have access to ?  Session ID, etc ?

Edit 2 : If Session End cannot be used to track disconnections, how does one track disconnections in ASP.Net ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session_End will be fired if one is using InProc.

Session_End will be fired 
1) after n minutes of inactivity (n = timeout value), or 
2) if someone calls Session.Abandon()

Session_End doesn't get fired if one closes the browser.

Session_End requires session state to be set.

If one needs the original Request.Browser data, one should save it in Session State.

During Session_End, it has access to the Session State.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to access the session in Session_End. I can't get to it...

Comment: void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

 string str = Session[browser];
    }

Answer (score 1):

No, the Request object is not available in Session End.

Note too that Session End only fires when you call Session.Abandon() from code, not when a Session expires due to natural timeout or what-have-you. Consequently, it is not a reliable method to use for tracking disconnections.

Comment: Hi Rex, thanks for your reply, how does one track the currently connected browser sessions in my application (eg Firefox 5 sessions, IE 10 sessions, etc).

Comment: From the MSDN docs "The Session_OnEnd subroutine is run when the Abandon method has been called or when the session has expired." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @GregB it does say that, but the first time I tried to figure out why Session_End wasn't working the way I expected, I left a debugger attached to the process with a breakpoint on my Session_End event and it was never hit, unless I explicitly called Session.Abandon()

Answer (score 0):

from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524689.aspx)

> The **Session_OnEnd** event occurs when a
>   session is abandoned or times out. Of
>   the Server built-in objects, only the
>   Application Object, Server Object, and
>   Session Object objects are available.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> You cannot call the Server.MapPath
>   method in the Session_OnEnd script. By
>   default, Session_OnEnd runs as the
>   Anonymous User, as defined for the
>   application. In the event that there
>   isn't an Anonymous user, or the Logon
>   for the Anonymous user fails, the
>   OnEnd function will not be called, and
>   an event will be logged.

Comment: I've never seen Session End fired when a session times out. Have you?

Comment: @Rex M: Session End only fires if you use in-process sessions, not if you use the state server or SQL Server as a session store.